# Verse in Isaiah 42:7 is referring to whom?

Tags: tanach, messiah

I was asked to clarify whether the question was referring to the "agent" or "patient", and the answer is that I was asking about the agent, not the patient. In other words, I was asking whether the agent who will release the captives, etc. is Moshiach or Israel.

[Isaiah 42:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.42.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) states the following: לפקח עינים עורות להוציא ממסגר אסיר מבית כלא ישבי חשך. This basically means - to paraphrase - opening the eyes of those deprived of light and rescuing those who sit in confinement and darkness (i.e., dungeon, prison). However, oftentimes, even when speaking in singular form, the verse is discussing Israel as a nation, not Moshiach as an individual person. Therefore, the question is, in this particular case, is is referring to Israel or to Moshiach? In other words, when we discuss rescuing those from darkness and confinement, etc. who are we referring to? Furthermore, if this verse/chapter is talking about Israel, are there are any others that discuss Moshiach doing similarly, and vice versa, if this verse/chapter is talking about Moshiach, are there any others that discuss Israel doing similarly?

I am asking about the agent, not the patient. In other words, I am asking whether the agent who will release the captives, etc. is Moshiach or Israel.

Comment: Hint: It's advised to read the entire chapter.

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to @AvrohomYitzchok answer:
Some commentators refer the God's agent as the Moshiach, all on verse 1 in the chapter [God's agent who is described in verse 1 will carry the tasks at verse 7]

Malbim on verse 1:

> עתה מתחיל לבאר מי הוא האיש אשר עליו דבר כל המחזה בסימן הקודם... הוא
>   עבדי שהוא המלך המשיח

Now [God] explains who is the the man that the prior vision referred to... he is my servant , who is the Moshiach-king.

Mezudat David on verse 1:

> . הנה עבדי אשר אתמך בו והוא מלך המשיח

Here is my servant who will gain my support - the Moshiach-king

Radak on verse 1

> הן עבדי. זהו מלך המשיח

Here is my servant - that's the Moshiach-king

Answer (score 0):

See the passage as shown in [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.42.7?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en) and see the commentators there.

None of the commentators there refer to Moshiach.
Ibn Ezra, Metzudas Dovid and Malbim refer to Israel explicitly.

I am unable to answer the second part of your question “are there are any others that discuss Moshiach doing similarly.”

Comment: WRONG. The Malbim an and Metzudat David explicitly say that it refers on the Moshich. Please edit your post.

Comment: @AlaychemRememberMonica I didn't check _Malbim_, but _M'tzudos_ says the verse is referring to the _mashiach_ removing Israel from captivity, etc. I don't know whether the OP is asking about [the agent or the patient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thematic_relation), but I suspect the latter, in which case Avrohom Yitzchok is completely correct that the verse is referring to Israel and not the _mashiach_.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I was asked to clarify whether the question was referring to the "agent" or "patient", and the answer is that I was asking about the agent, not the patient. In other words, I was asking whether the agent who will release the captives, etc. is Moshiach or Israel. –